# Problemas na rota

Tags: laravel

Boa tarde pessoal, estou implementando o metodo destroy no meu codigo, ao clicar no botão queria que exibir a tela do form com os dados peenchidos e o botao de confirmação de exclusao.
Ja fiz a view com a tela do destroy porem quando clico no botão pra mandar pra tela de exclusao esta dando esse erro:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.
```

Ja revisei as rotas mas não consigo acerta esse caminho pode me ajudar?

Segue os código

ROTA:

```php
Route::delete('destroyfuncionario/{id}', [FuncionarioController::class, 'destroyfuncionario'])->name('destroyfuncionario');
```

Controler:

```php
    public function destroyfuncionario(Funcionario $id)
    {
        Funcionario::find($id)->delete();

        return view('funcionario.funcionarios')
            ->with('msg', 'Funcionário excluído com sucesso');
    }
```

Botão para tela do destroy:

```html
<a href "{{route('destroyfuncionario', ['id'=>$funcionario])}}" class= "btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm edit-btn btn-lg float-right ml-1"> <ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon> Excluir </a>
```

na view destroyfuncionario:

```
form method="POST" action="{{route('destroyfuncionario', ['id'=> $funcionario->id])}}"
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
```

Agradecido

Comment: Pedro sugiro formatar com qualidade os códigos em suas perguntas, caso contrário elas podem ser fechadas sem respostas.

Comment: Provavelmente falta o sinal de igual em: `<a href "{{route`, deveria ser `<a href="{{route`

Answer (score -2):

Você tem uma única rota, atendendo ao método DELETE, porém espera que ao clicar no botão, que na verdade é um link, por padrão o navegador realiza o request usando o método GET.

O que você precisa é adicionar uma nova rota, atendendo por GET, que mostra a view `destroyfuncionario`.

```php
Route::get('destroyfuncionario/{id}', [FuncionarioController::class, 'showDestroyFuncionario'])->name('destroyfuncionario.show');
```

Também é necessário criar o método `showDestroyFuncionario` que usei no exemplo.

Desta maneira, a rota que você já tinha criado, atendendo ao método DELETE, será chamada pela view com o form que a executa por meio do submit correto.

Não esqueça que os nomes são sugestões, pode alterar o nome da rota e do método.

Para deixar mais explícita a explicação, cada rota (neste exemplo) atende um método, por isso podemos usar a mesma url para direcionar à métodos diferentes.

Answer (score -2):

Por padrão o destroy no Laravel chama o método HTTP DELETE, que por trás nada mais é que um POST com um nome diferente. No seu form que confirma a exclusão precisa passar o method POST e passar uma diretiva do blade com o método DELETE. Segue o exemplo:

```
<form action="{{route('delete', 'id'=>9999))}}" method="POST">


@method('DELETE')

<button type="submit">Excluir</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).